# SQL Server 2008 SQL Spatial LINESTRING Manipulation

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a LINESTRING stored in my table and I need to know at what end of the string a point lies on. The idea is that I need to know what "direction" the LINESTRING was defined in so that I can calculate a distance down the line in the appropriate manner (which I already know how to do). Anybody have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It will be helpful if you post a little data from the LINESTRING column in your database.

Comment: I did not populate the table and for security reasons, I cannot disclose the data within the table. Hopefully, all you need to know is that the strings represent a few thousand meters of distance on the earth's surface and every string has two endpoints. I need to figure out what those endpoints are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across the answer. `STStartPoint()` and `STEndPoint()` are functions you can call on a LINESTRING instance to get POINT objects representing what the function names imply.